# Spring3.0+Hibernate4.0 pom.xml file

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I was trying to build a spring3.0 and Hibernate4.0 project using maven..In my dao folder, I have this file interface for the dao(data abstract object) but the import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion import cannot be found..there is an error there saying:"**the import org.hibernate cannot be resolved**". could it be the pom.xml file not properly filled? I have below also my pom.xml.. Thanks for your time.

```
package com.henry.rep.dao;

import org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion;


import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public interface AbstractDao<E, I extends Serializable> {

    E findById(I id);
    void saveOrUpdate(E e);
    void delete(E e);
    List<E> findByCriteria(Criterion criterion);
}



                       **
```

### ## Heading ##POM.XML

**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.henry.rep</groupId>
    <artifactId>Spring3Hibernate4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Spring3Hibernate4</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <org.springframework.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
        <org.spring.security.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</org.spring.security.version>
        <org.slf4j.version>1.6.1</org.slf4j.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add the following dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- dependencies additions ends here.. -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding this to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.6.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Hopefully, that should make a difference.

Comment: I have this already :
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
is it not the same?

Comment: Unfortunately, that are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be with your IDE because the samples you provided compile fine.  Have you tried building from the command line with `mvn compile`?

Comment: well, you are not including enough information for me to help you.  I took the pom and java file you provided, put it in a maven project and it compiled fine.  I'd like to help but I don't see a problem

Comment: could you send me your email and i will send you the full file. I can't send everything here. I am guessing it is my pom.xml file

Comment: I cannot give you my email, besides it defeats the purpose of stackoverflow which is to help others.  If you have a differen't pom file that the one posted and its the problem, you have a dependency conflict.  Try use 'mvn dependency:tree'  and try to see if you have conflicting library versions.

Comment: I don't have any other pom file.

Comment: Then what were you going to send me in an email?

Answer (score 0):

If the above suggestions have not worked, you may want to try adding this to your pom.xml file:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    <id>hibernate-support</id>
    <layout>default</layout>
    <name>Repository for library Library[hibernate-support]</name>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: nothing works. It is complaining of the spring and hibernate imports. I thought since those are in the pom file, it should be OK but I was wrong. I do not want to start importing dependencies manually into a lib folder for it was against such that I started out using a maven project